# Using special fields in a parameter

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use a special field in a parameter. I am working on a set of reports that will be printed and mailed out. The print shop wants to be able to separate them into all 1 page reports, all 2 page reports, all 3 page reports and so on. I have set up the *Page N of M* to reset page number after and new page after the appropriate footer. So is it possible to use *Page N of M* in a parameter so you can select all the 1 page reports or all the 2 page reports and so on?

Comment: How are you creating parameters? Static or dynamic

Comment: I suggest you to use your visual studio language or your database to find the number of rows of your query then you need to know how many rows make your report multi-page and .... ;).

Comment: I am using static parameters. What is the difference?